# SC Query returns errors when used in BATCH FILE 'FOR' loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, service

Trying to use the following line of code in a Batch File FOR loop:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%g IN ('sc query type=service ^| FIND /I "bthserv"') DO ( ECHO %%g )
```

The command in brackets works successfully when used from CMD Prompt.

However, in a FOR loop it simply returns:

> [SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 123:
>
> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Is anyone familiar with this error and how to get the FOR loop to report all services with the specific, or similar name(s)?

**[Edit /]**

Even changing the command to this fails with the same message:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%g IN ('sc query type^= service ^| FIND /I "bthserv"') DO ( ECHO %%g )
```

Comment: You need to escape the `=` symbol.

Comment: I was putting an answer together @Squashman, when you posted this. Whilst you're correct, it wasn't the only issue.

Comment: Incorporated the escape character and modifed the thread title...

Comment: Also, the `type= service` isn't needed, because it's the default option, so technically `type=` will work exactly the same. Are you positive that you're looking for a `service` `type`, and not a `driver` or to be safe `all`, i.e. `query type= all` or `query type= driver`.

Comment: @Arianax, I have rolled back your edit. Please do not use the question area to include solutions to your question. We have an answer area for that purpose. You are free to provide an answer in that area, and if you wish, select it as your accepted solution. Please do not abuse, or try to change, the way this site currently works; thank you.

Comment: It's not a full answer to the question, so I used the Edit for that. It's only a workaround, not a whole solution... and I'm quite certain you should be posting these criticisms in Meta Stack Exchange, not on the thread itself.

Comment: @Arianax, you clearly wrote "Seems I've found the **ANSWER**" and then posted some code. You additionally decided to ask another question after that. You should limit questions to one per post, multiple questions are considered too broad. In addition to that, if you add additional questions once you've already received answers, those answers can no longer be solutions, unless their authors then update their answers accordingly. That would be discourteous as it would mean in order to have their answer accepted they'd be compelled to give you more of their time.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, your title is confusing because it uses `queryex` not `query` as in your code.

In addition to that `query type=service` is not valid, it should be `query type= service`, *(the space after the `=` is required)*.

However, I'm a little confused also by your command, I'm unsure whether you're wanting to know if there's an active service named `bthserv`, or if there's an active service with a name containing the case insensitive string `bthserv`.

If you're wanting to know if there's an active service named `bthserv`, you should really just query it by name, `query bthserv`. From there you can simply use `&&` and `||` for successful and unsuccessful commands, *(I've just used `Echo` commands below)*.

Example:

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%sc.exe query bthserv 1> NUL && (Echo bthserv is an installed service) || Echo bthserv is not an installed service
```

Alternatively, you can use the `ErrorLevel`.

Example:

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%sc.exe query bthserv 1> NUL
@If ErrorLevel 1 (Echo bthserv is not an installed service)Else Echo bthserv is an installed service
```

If you're wanting to know if there's an active service with a name containing the case insensitive string `bthserv`, *(not matching it)*, then the [find](/questions/tagged/find) command is okay.

However, when you run that command within a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), the `=` character is treated as a delimiter by the `cmd.exe` instance, the command is passed to. You'll therefore need to escape it, using the caret, `^`. In addition to that, if you want the matched service name to be captured, you'll need to select everything after the first token, using the default       and <kbd>TAB</kbd> delimiters.

Example:

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%sc.exe query type^= service ^| %__AppDir__%find.exe /I "bthserv"') Do @Echo %%H
```

However, you could also enclose the entire string passed to the `cmd.exe` instance in doublequotes, and not need to escape anything.

Example:

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%G In ('"%__AppDir__%sc.exe query type= service | %__AppDir__%find.exe /I "bthserv""') Do @Echo %%H
```

Comment: Have you tested your above commands? The result in a range of errors when used in  batch file with Delayed Expansion switched on. Either that or I'm still doing something wrong. Can't even get 'SC Query type= service' to run even when it's not in the for loop but as a standalone command, within batch.

Comment: None of those commands are wrong @Arianax, you are mistaken! And I don't need to test them, even if I had a PC to test them on, I know they're correct. Additionally none of them are affected by delayed expansion because they aren't using variables which are defined within the same code block. And please do not change your question completely to make changes after you've received an answer. I've modified your question so that the original code, at my time of answering remains, and your changes added as an edit.

Comment: As `ERROR 123` is `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`, it appears to me that you're not using the exact code I have provided, and/or you're trying to query a service which has not been installed/created/started correctly. Please provide the rest of the code, up to that point, so that we can further diagnose your issues, outside of the appropriate fixes I've provided for your initially posted code. _(You can do that by adding to your **[Edit /]** section again)_.

Comment: If you're still using `SC` instead of `sc.exe` or the always correct `%__AppDir__%sc.exe`? you can have issues, one of them being if you mistakenly name your batch file `sc.bat` or `sc.cmd`. What that will do is effectively run your script again, from within itself, and with `query …` as its arguments. _(That would obviously be a problem)_. Another being if the contents of `%PATH%` or `%PATHEXT%` have been modified, accidentally or otherwise!

Comment: Please don't edit my post. I mentioned you and Squashman in my Edit subtext. You've just redundantly re-edited an edit... Also, I ran your code. It doesn't provide an error but it doesn't seem to do anything at all, that is, it doesn't return anything...

Comment: I will edit your post, @Arianax, or any other, when its modification has made the answers more difficult to follow. The majority of what I posted was to show you errors in your provided code, as soon as you changed that code, you effectively negated the majority of what I posted. The correct way for you to have made your modification was to append the new code, not replace it. I informed you of that, and as a courtesy did it for you. You were also told that my code is correct and if you have further errors to add the rest of your missing code to the question; we cannot assist you without it.

Comment: You have further sidetracked the issue with all the above posts. Not clarified it. While you were doing that I found a workaround... Try Meta Stack Exchange to complain about the post.

Comment: Good luck with finding a solution for your issues @Arianax.